# Google Places Autocomplete React Component

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, google-places-api, react-on-rails

I'm learning react and trying to create a Google places autocomplete component, inside a rails app the using react on rails gem. Here's what I have so far, need some help finishing it off.

I think I'm having an issue getting the Google javascript library to load correctly.  See error message from console below (note I have the proper [KEY] running in my app).

```
Navigated to https://react-on-rails-basic-tutorial-mcl282.c9users.io/
js?key=[KEY]&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete:102 Uncaught Yc {message: "initAutocomplete is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new Yc (https://maps.googleapis.com/m…libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete:139:73"}
Yg @ js?key=[KEY]&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete:102
(anonymous) @ js?key=[KEY]&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete:139
google.maps.Load @ js?key=[KEY]&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete:21
(anonymous) @ js?key=[KEY]&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete:138
(anonymous) @ js?key=[KEY]&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete:139
createReactElement.js?74ab:40 RENDERED GoogleAutoComplete to dom node with id: GoogleAutoComplete-react-component-f9a3e037-df00-4f35-9a7c-103c33b1208e with props, railsContext: Object {text: "google autocomplete"} Object {inMailer: false, i18nLocale: "en", i18nDefaultLocale: "en", href: "https://react-on-rails-basic-tutorial-mcl282.c9users.io/", location: "/"…}
clientStartup.js?0ac5:149 Uncaught TypeError: ReactOnRails encountered an error while rendering component: GoogleAutoComplete.Original message: Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined
    at GoogleAutoComplete.initAutocomplete (eval at <anonymous> (webpack-bundle.self-cdcd22e….js?body=1:3586), <anonymous>:44:48)
    at GoogleAutoComplete.componentDidMount (eval at <anonymous> (webpack-bundle.self-cdcd22e….js?body=1:3586), <anonymous>:38:12)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (webpack-bundle.self-cdcd22e….js?body=1:2842), <anonymous>:265:25)
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (eval at <anonymous> (webpack-bundle.self-cdcd22e….js?body=1:2842), <anonymous>:75:12)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (webpack-bundle.self-cdcd22e….js?body=1:2842), <anonymous>:264:11)
    at CallbackQueue.notifyAll (eval at <anonymous> (webpack-bundle.self-cdcd22e….js?body=1:2296), <anonymous>:76:22)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.close (eval at <anonymous> (webpack-bundle.self-cdcd22e….js?body=1:3004), <anonymous>:80:26)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.closeAll (eval at <anonymous> (webpack-bundle.self-cdcd22e….js?body=1:2398), <anonymous>:206:25)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (eval at <anonymous> (webpack-bundle.self-cdcd22e….js?body=1:2398), <anonymous>:153:16)
    at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (eval at <anonymous> (webpack-bundle.self-cdcd22e….js?body=1:3130), <anonymous>:126:15)
```

Here is the relevant code:

index.html.erb

```
<html>
  <body>
  <%= react_component("GoogleAutoComplete") %>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAnhYQqHo2V5AcFpcKKPX6rz0bVrw7xmZg&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

GoogleAutoComplete.jsx

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

export default class GoogleAutoComplete extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    }
  constructor(props) {

      super(props);
        this.state = { 
          autocomplete: {} 
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.initAutocomplete();
    }

    initAutocomplete() {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
      const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((this.refs.autoCompletePlaces), {types: ['geocode']});

      autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', this.fillInAddress);
      this.setState({ autocomplete });
    }

    geolocate() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          const geolocation = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
          };
        });
      }
    }

    fillInAddress() {
      const componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
      };
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
      const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      for (let component in componentForm) {
        this.refs.component.value = '';
        this.refs.component.disabled = false;
      }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (let i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      const addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
      if (componentForm[addressType]) {
        const val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
        this.refs.addressType.value = val;
      }
    }
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="locationField">
          <input 
            id="autocomplete" 
            placeholder="Enter your address"
            onFocus={this.geolocate}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            ref="autoCompletePlaces"
          />
        </div>
        <table id="address">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Street address</td>
              <td>
                <input 
                  id="street_number"
                  disabled="true"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input 
                  id="route"
                  disabled="true"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>City</td>
              <td>
                <input 
                  id="locality"
                  disabled="true"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>State</td>
              <td>
                <input 
                  id="administrative_area_level_1" 
                  disabled="true"/>
                </td>
              <td>Zip code</td>
              <td>
                <input
                  id="postal_code"
                  disabled="true"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Country</td>
              <td>
                <input
                  id="country" 
                  disabled="true"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>      
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Michael, I know this is an old post but there is an API key in the html script in your question - might be worth editing and removing it :).

If you ever want to use this as a react hook, I have a post that would help with creating/using the hook with the google places autocomplete service here: https://atomizedobjects.com/blog/react/how-to-use-google-autocomplete-with-react-hooks/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because the `initComplete()` is not available in the global scope. The `initComplete()` is a React component method and you cannot call it outside the component.

To pass the `callback` parameter to Google Maps API, you need to load the library asynchronously, without using the `<script>` tag like you did.

Please have a look at the following repository to see how they handle the asynchronous loading of Google Maps library.

https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react

Comment: I think I understand the concept here, need to load the higher order component with the Google Maps API script in it, giving the component I made the functions it needs.  However, I don't really understand how to implement it.  They give this code example: 'import {GoogleApiWrapper} from 'GoogleMapsReactComponent'

// ...

export class Container extends React.Component {}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: __GAPI_KEY__
})(Container)'  How do I implement this with my GoogleAutoComplete.jsx component?

Comment: @MichaelLee The `GoogleApiWrapper` component passes down the `loaded` prop to the wrapped component. This prop is set to true only after the library is loaded. When a prop changes, the wrapped component will render itself again and you can check if the `loaded` is true in `componentDidMount()` and call the `initAutocomplete()` if it is true.

Comment: this works!  1 thing that really tripped me up was that the blog has an error, see this link:  https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/issues/18;

Comment: I am trying to do this as well and understand what is happening conceptually, but do not know how to implement it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46780770/utilizing-google-maps-in-other-components-through-withscriptjs-withgooglemap - do you have any suggestions? It looks like the library you linked to has a helper specific to it, and since there's no activity on the repo for awhile I'd rather not include it.